# Текст вместо RecyclerView при отсутствии подключения к интернету

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть приложение с загрузкой изображений из интернета в RecyclerView. И хотелось бы, чтобы при отключенном интернете вместо RecyclerView отображался TextView с соответствующим сообщением об отсутствии подключения к интернету.
Попадались решения, где просто создавали новый layout с TextView с текстом "Нет интернет подключения" и в зависимости от того, есть подключение или нет происходит переключение между этим макетом и макетом с RecyclerView. Но, как мне показалось, это немного странно. Может быть, есть более изящное решение?

Comment: Тогда создайте `FrameLayout` с двумя другими `ViewGroup`: один будет макетом для нормальной работы, а другой - в условиях отсутствия интернета. А в активности изменяйте видимость для них

Comment: если вам это кажется странным используйте 2 фрагмента

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение тут достаточно простое, вот небольшой пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_light_background"
    tools:context=".ui.moviedetails.fragments.ReviewsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_data_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/empty_search_text_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/app_primary_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/empty_search_text_size"
            tools:text="@string/empty_search_text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_search_result"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

В вашей `View` если вы получаете корректные данные то делаете

```
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
emptyDataScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

в случае отсутствия интернета тоже самое только наоборот, скрываете `Recycler` и показываете `emptyScreen`.

Выдумывать какие-то другие велосипеды тут нет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать свой класс основанный на `RV`, например `RecyclerViewEmpty.java`:

```
public class RecyclerViewEmpty extends RecyclerView {
    private View emptyView;

    private AdapterDataObserver emptyObserver = new AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            Adapter<?> adapter =  getAdapter();
            if(adapter != null && emptyView != null) {
                if(adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    RecyclerViewEmpty.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    RecyclerViewEmpty.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
    };

    public RecyclerViewEmpty(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmpty(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmpty(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter != null) {
            adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(emptyObserver);
        }
        emptyObserver.onChanged();
    }

    public void setEmptyView(View emptyView) {
        this.emptyView = emptyView;
    }
}
```

Ваша разметка должна содержать и `RecyclerViewEmpty` и нужный `View`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   ...>

   <local.example.mytest.RecyclerViewEmpty
        android:id="@+id/RVlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Все что нужно сделать в основном классе, это объявить `View` и передать его в `RV`:

```
...
TextView emptyText=findViewById(R.id.emptyText);
recyclerView.setEmptyView(emptyText);
...
```

Вместо `TextView` в разметке можете использовать любой другой `View`. Например `Layout` содержащий `ImageView` `TextView` и тд

Comment: У меня только один вопрос. А нафига адаптеру знать об этой View??? Если тоже самое можно написать за пределами адаптера? Так ваш адаптер начинает зависеть от какой-то View которая ему вообще нет нужна.

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, 1 - это вариант реализации. Или вы считаете что только вы правы? 2  - зачем включать лишние эмоции? Поставили минус - идите дальше!

Comment: Я не считаю, что только я прав. Но создавать лишнюю зависимость на ровном месте не правильно. Зачем RecycleView знать о каких-то View которыми он не должен управлять? Тем более если тоже самое можно сделать к примеру на входе в Adapter. Мало того что это лишняя зависимость, так еще и в адаптере лишний код. По сути вы сделали тоже самое, что и в моем ответе, только прокинули это еще дальше, туда где это не нужно в принципе

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, причем здесь адаптер? Класс никак не влияет на логику существующего адаптера.

Comment: Смотрите у вас есть кейс в котором либо есть список либо есть какой-то EmptyScreen. Вообще по хорошему что показать должен какой-нибудь Presenter, который устанавливает во View к примеру State.EMPTY или State.CONTENT. В более просто варианте можно сделать чтоб сама View посмотрела если список пуст то отобразила Empty иначе Content. Вы же эту ответственность вешаете на Adapter, т.е. еще дальше. Если у вас завтра поменяется принцип отображения пустой View (например ваш дизайнер захочет паттерн скелетон) вы будете менять код и в  Activity и в Adapter-е.

Comment: Ко всему прочему вы нарушаете принцип SOLID - Принцип единой ответственности. Адаптер не должен решать показывать ему пустую View или нет, он должен уметь только рисовать списки не больше. Он не должен знать о тех View которых находятся за пределами RecyclerView. А что если вы захотите переиспользовать этот адаптер ,а в другом экране нет EmptyView или в случае пустого списка открывается другой экран или отправляется запрос еще куда-то? Вы получите мертвый код.

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, еще раз - кастомный RV никак не влияет на адаптер! Сколько раз нужно написать, чтобы суть дошла?

Comment: Да сорян, я ошибся с адаптером. Только сути это не меняет. Все описанное выше можно отнести и сюда. Как уже упоминалось выше, а что если там будет не TextView, а что-то более хитрое? Нет ну конечно можно, только вот зачем непонятно.

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, работает с любым View, не только TextView. Что передаете, то и будет скрываться/отображаться. Для чего нужно? Например у меня выполняются запросы к БД из разных методов, раньше я всегда забывал добавлять строку проверки, нужно ли показать сообщение о том что результат не найден или нет, с этим классом я всегда знаю, что сообщение покажется при пустом результате поиска, не зависимо от того какой метод вызвал изменения адаптера.

Comment: Лан. Я не хочу устраивать тут холивар. Может я не прав. Вы имеете право на свое мнение, я на свое. Но мне кажется это лишнее.  Зачем писать код который можно не писать, и я все ещё считаю, что нарушен принцип единой ответственности.